# Tympanus Elastislide : main image sliding animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, elastislide

I am using tympanus Elastislide Carousel Responsive jQuery plugin for my website. The plugin works perfectly on my site.

But, I want to add animation on main image sliding left to right.

plugin link : https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/

I try to do apply code on this line in `gallery.js` :

```
$rgGallery.find('div.rg-image').empty().append('<img src="' + largesrc + '"/>');
```

But, it's not working

Anyone can tell me how to do it?

Thanks.